# Jquery hover cancel action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

I want to display a div when you hover over another DOM element, but I want to cancel this action if you move the mouse before the div is shown. So far this is what I have

HTML

```
<div id="msg">
    <a href="#" id="33"> HERE </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var timer;
$("body").on('mouseenter', '#msg a',function(){
    var userHover = $(this).attr("id");
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        alert(userHover);   
    }, 1000);
}).on('mouseleave', '#msg a', function(){

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nyrdz/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you just want do clear the timeout?    in that case `clearTimeout(timer)` should do the trick ...

Comment: well it is more like if the user moves the mouse from the 'a' element before the div pops up, the div doesn't get shown and the div that is to be shown is an info box somewhere else of course. Will clearing the timeout cancel this call? Just want to be clear thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout):

```
var timer;
$("body").on('mouseenter', '#msg a', function(){
    var userHover = $(this).attr("id");
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        alert(userHover);   
    }, 1000);
}).on('mouseleave', '#msg a', function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

However, in case you have more than one element matching `#msg a` I'd highly recommend you to store the `timer` value in the element-specific data.

```
$("body").on('mouseenter', '#msg a', function(){
    var userHover = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function () {
        alert(userHover);   
    }, 1000));
}).on('mouseleave', '#msg a', function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, within the `#msg` there are multiple `a` elements

Comment: Thanks it fits my current problem :)